# How to number section and detail view for a same drawing

Tags: technical-drawing

For a given 2D print, is it recommended to number section views and details views with the same alphabetical list, i.e. Section views A,B and C followed by detail views D, E and F,

or go with different alphabetical list, i.e. Section views, A, B and C, followed by detail views, A, B and C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first suggestion is correct - there should not be two different views (of any type) with the same letter on any one drawing.

See the quote below from ASME Y14.3-2003

> **1.7.3 Identifying Removed Views.** To relate the viewing
>   plane or cutting plane to its removed view, capital
>   letters such as A, B, C, etc., are placed near each arrowhead.
>   The corresponding removed views are identified
>   as VIEW A-A, VIEW B-B, VIEW C-C, etc. View letters
>   should be used in alphabetical order excluding I, O, Q,
>   S, X, and Z. When the alphabet is exhausted, additional
>   removed views shall be identified by double letters in
>   alphabetical order, as in AA-AA, AB-AB, AC-AC, etc.

This applies to *all* "Removed Views", of any type.
I, O, Q, S, X, and Z are all excluded due to their visual similarity to 1, 0, 0, 5, [blank that needs filling in], and 2, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Really appreciate you providing a source with it.